# how to declare value as none the redeclare it then use it for an if statement in python?

Tags: python, function, variables, pycharm, speech-recognition

My question is pretty simple how do how to declare value as none the redeclare it then use it for an if statement in python?

```
global command
command = None

def user_commands():
    def take_command():
    try:
        with sr.Microphone() as source:
            print('listening...')
            voice = listener.listen(source)
            command = listener.recognize_google(voice)
            command = command.lower()
            if 'alexa' in command:
                command = command.replace('alexa', '')
                print(command)
    except:
        pass
    return command

def run_alexa():
    global command
    command = user_commands()
    ...

    if 'Play' in command:
        ...
```

what is happening when I do this is:
TypeError: argument of type 'NoneType' is not iterable

What I am doing is creating an alexa which ask to take commands then do the command. the variable for the command is set equal to the person says but in python it doesnt like to have a variable without a type so I said no then said ill redeclare it but it does not work,

Comment: What is `command` in the context of `user_commands()`?

Comment: Why do you need `command` as a global variable? `user_commands` should just return an appropriate value for `run_alexa` to assign to `command` as a local variable.

Comment: because user_commands uses command to get the value

Comment: But apparently `rux_alexa` uses `user_commands` to get a value for `command`. If `user_commands` also needs the value of `command` to come from somewhere else, where is the actual value for `command` supposed to come from?

Comment: here  basicly this

```
def take_command():
    try:
        with sr.Microphone() as source:
            print('listening...')
            voice = listener.listen(source)
            command = listener.recognize_google(voice)
            command = command.lower()
            if 'alexa' in command:
                command = command.replace('alexa', '')
                print(command)
    except:
        pass
    return command

Comment: In your own words: what part of the code should cause the `def take_command():` function to run?

Comment: Why is `take_command()` a sub-function inside of `user_commands()`?  What is the purpose?

Answer (score 1):

The global keyword can be deceptive. It is not used for declaring a global variable, but rather for instructing the interpreter about what scope to use in future variable references. Let me try to explain it in another way:

When you write `global command` you’re trying to say “interpreter, please create a global variable named command”. But in reality `global command` actually means “interpreter, whenever you see a variable named command inside this function, you should look for it in the global scope”.

With all that said, you just need to define the variable in the global scope (outside any functions). Then, all functions that want to access this global variable should include the expression `global command`:

```
command = None

def user_commands():
    ...
    ...
    return command

def run_alexa():
    global command
    command = user_commands()
```

Comment: There's no need for `command = None` as long as `run_alexa` is called to define the variable before anyone else tries to read it.

Comment: `global command` does not just mean "look in the global scope". Any free variable (assuming no intervening non-local scopes) will automatically be looked up in the global or built-in scope. The sole purpose of `global` is to allow *assignments* to names in the global scope, instead of defining a new local variable.

Answer (score -1):

In your particular case, you are using the variable before you set it - which is not exclusive to `global` variables. That said; you may be confused on how the `global` keyword works.

`global` allows you to create, or modify, a variable from within an enclosed scope, that will be elevated to the global scope.

For example, you can try this in your REPL:

```py
 >>> foo = "x"
 >>>
 >>> def bar():
 ...     foo = "y"
 ...
 >>> print(foo)
 'x'
 >>> bar()
 >>> print(foo)
 'x'
```

If you use the `global` keyword, however, it will be set when you modify it in the function.

```py
 >>> foo = "x"
 >>>
 >>> def bar():
 ...     global foo
 ...     foo = "y"
 ...
 >>> print(foo)
 'x'
 >>> bar()
 >>> print(foo)
 'y'
```

Comment: "TL;DR: You need to declare the global var somewhere (in the global scope), first." No, you don't. Try `del foo; bar(); print(foo)`. `bar` can provide the initial definition of `foo`, not just modify the value of an existing `foo`.